# Selenium ElementNotFoundException when the element in a loop

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Am writing the selenium code for an element. It gives the error as `ElementNotFoundException`

I know the reason that the element was hidden or its style is none.
I Googled and I found the following solution:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) this.webdriver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elementToClick);
```

…but my element in a loop. For the first iteration it is successful but in the further iterations it is throwing the same exception.

Can anyone explain the `arguments[0]`?

Comment: It's probably because you are navigating to another URL when you click that element. Publish the URL of the web-page that you are trying to control (or at least the relevant piece of HTML), and I might be able to suggest a different approach.

Comment: `arguments[0]` is a reference to the items you are passing in as **arguments**. Since arrays in JS are zero-based, `0` refers the first item (element) you are passing it (i.e since you are only passing in one anyway, it'll be the `elementToClick` DOM object). Post a snippet of the code you are using, the HTML of the page, the versions of your browsers and Selenium and the **full* error and stack trace.

Comment: Yes, after clicking am navigating into the other page.It is giving error as ElementNotFoundException in the second run.First Run is successful

Comment: You haven't done any of what we have asked. Well what happens when the element is clicked? Do you navigate to a new page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in your example, "arguments[0]" = elementToClick .   Also, I only use a JavascriptExecutor when I have no other options to click something, and that almost never happens.   For example, I use JavascriptExecutor to do page-downs because Selenium doesn't have a feature that does that properly.

So, if the element you are seeking really does have a 'display=none' set on it, what you should do instead is use an [ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) condition with a WebDriverWait (or a FluentWait).

For all other cases of elements which are visible or not visible at times, use ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated.

Using the Wait classes with ExpectedConditions, you can use a while loop to **ignore** certain exceptions and do re-tries until the condition is satisfied.

Comment: thank u for your reply... this statement is fine when it is executing for the first time.. second time it is not working.. can u please help me?